# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

This is my login code. Unhandledpromises occour while comparing Users input password and stored password.

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  try {    
    const {email, password} = req.body
    console.log(req.body)

    if(!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).render('login', {
        message: 'Please Provide an email and password'
      })
    }

    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ',{email}, async (error, results) => {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(results)
        if( !results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password)) ) {
          res.status(401).render('login', {
            message: 'Email or Password is Incorrect'
          })
      }
     })

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Console.log(error) is null..

**Updated**
[image: database]

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to `promisify` `db.query` so you can `await` it, the errors will then be properly caught in the `catch` block, and your code will be flattened.

Your error is caused by `results[0]` which is `undefined` when trying to access its `password` property, which means that `results` is an empty array.

The second argument of `query` should not be an `Object` but an `Array`, so replace `{ email }` with `[email]`:

```
const {
    promisify
} = require('util');

const query = promisify(db.query.bind(db));

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {
            email,
            password
        } = req.body;

        if (!email || !password) {
            return res.status(400).render('login', {
                message: 'Please Provide an email and password'
            });
        }

        const results = await query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ', [email]); // problem occur due to usage of curly brackets.
            
        if (!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password))) {
            res.status(401).render('login', {
                message: 'Email or Password is Incorrect'
            });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work still cannot read the property password at results[0].password

Comment: I am also thinking the same but how should I catch the data from the database instead of that.

Comment: My answer doesn't solve your problem (I'd need more information for that) it just points out why `console.log(error)` didn't work for you (fixes `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`), and it suggests the cause of your problem (probably the request returning an empty dataset)

Comment: You should verify that the `email` variable is properly extracted from the `body`, verify that you don't have encoding issues, and verify that you have an actual record in the database with this exact email address.

Comment: console.log(results) is not logging anything so does that mean my query is not drawing any data from the database

Comment: What do you mean by "not logging anything"? Do you see `[]`? `{}`?

Comment: nothing at all no response wait let me update the question with my console snapshot and database snapshot.

Comment: Then it's your database returning nothing.

Comment: You should remove the curly braces around `email` in the query parameters and replace them with square brackets: `const results = await query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ', [email]);`

Comment: yeah I was checking how the query is injected in the database thanks for your help it works.